# Why Easin Function Not Working Here

Tags: jquery, html

```
 function techSlide() {

    var now = - 230;
    $(".imgContentSlideMask").animate({ SlideNext: now }, {step: function (val, fx) {
         $(".imgContentSlideMask").css('-webkit-transform', "translateY(" + val + "px)");      
         $(".imgContentSlideMask").css('-moz-transform', "translateY(" + val + "px)");
        },
        duration: 700
    }, 'easeInOutBounce');
};
```

Easing function  Not Working At All

Comment: Do you have the jQuery UI library included?

Comment: yahh.....................

Comment: you didn't tag it. Are you positive jquery UI, not just jquery?

Comment: other easing functions working well at some other place the in same page, but not here.. so there's an alternate of this

Comment: others such as `swing` and `linear`? Those are the only two available with the jQuery library alone. I included the link to jQuery's docks so you can read it from them. You don't have to take my word for it. If others are working, you're using an additional plugin that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: all sort of ease are working, and they working without using any additional plugins

Comment: I'd really like to see a live demo of that. I'm really curious how those easings can work when even jQuery says they don't exist.

Comment: except this one jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 1):

Additional easings, such as `easeInOutBounce`, for jQuery animations are made available by including the jQuery UI library in addition to the jQuery library.

See **[jQuery UI (click)](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)**.

Here's the CDN link for quick inclusion in your project:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The only easings available with just the jQuery library are `swing` and `linear`. See the jQuery **[docs (click)](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing)**.